# How to disconnect the user by emitting disconnect event in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Below is my server script. I want to show " a particular user has left the chat" by clicking `leave` button `index.html` which is emitting 'disconnect' event. But this doesn't seem to work. I guess it implies that default event can't be emitted. Plz help me do that. Any sort of help is appreciated.

**socket.js**

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection',function(socket)
{
  //console.log("user connected")
  socket.on('new user', function(data) {
    console.log(data);})
    socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
        console.log(data);

})

})
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE   html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
  <style>

  </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>


<script>
  var socket = io.connect();
 //
 $(function(){

  $('#join').click(function(){
    var name= $('input').val(); 
    socket.emit('new user', name +  ' has just joined the chat');     
  })

  $('#leave').click(function(){
    var name= $('input').val(); 
    socket.emit('disconnect', name +  ' has left the chat');     
  })



 })

</script>


 Choose your username <input type="text">
      <button id="join" type="submit">
      Enter
      </button>
      <button id="leave" type="submit">
          Leave
      </button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

  socket.on('new user', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })

  http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
  })
}
```

Comment: sorry i hadnt read the question properly, I edited it try again :)